# PDOexception :There is no active transaction

Tags: php, database

Hi I get the "There is no active transaction" when I run my code below:

```
public function Login($username, $password)
{
    try
    {
        $database = db_camagru();
        $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE (username=:username OR email=:username) AND password=:password";
        $database->exec($query);
        $database->commit();
        if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $result->id;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit($e->getMessage() . "kwezi");
    }
}
```

the error seems to be coming from my `$database->commit();` line.

Comment: you are trying to `commit` a transaction, though you never started one. Just remove that line.

Comment: useful reads: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: @mario the question is why would anyone want to make a transaction for a single `SELECT` query. ;-)

Comment: @Kwezi you do not bind variables to the query!?

Comment: also it seems like you are storing _plain passwords_ in your database. __do never do that__! Use password_hash() and password_verify()

Comment: @mario PDO allows that now, maybe it depends on using `ATTR_EMULATES_PREPARE`

Comment: @Jeff when I remove that line it gives me a "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on string..." error.. I'm fairly new to this so I'm trying to wrap my mind around it... and I will hash the passwords, just kept forgetting them after I create a user, so I just unhashed them for now

Comment: You seem to want [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or perhaps [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), not [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php).  See examples in the documentation for how to use it, including what the function returns.

Comment: @Kwezi I also tend to forget the passwords of my test users. That's why they have all the same password 'password' (of course only on my local dev env). Better implement it now, because it will change the logic quite a bit.

Comment: _"I'm fairly new to this"_ - fair enough, we are here to help. A good start is always [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with it's examples